# What's the equivalent of NumberInt() from the mongo shell in client JavaScript?

Tags: mongodb

In the MongoDB shell, I can insert an integer value of `1` by using the `NumberInt(1)` type coercion.

How can I do that from client JavaScript that uses the [mongodb module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb)?

Answer (score 6):

The [Node.js MongoDB driver](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/) API exposes three integer types:

- [Int32](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Int32.html)
- [Long (64-bit)](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Long.html)
- [Decimal128](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.3/api/Decimal128.html)

Choose the one that best fits your data range and use it like this:

```js
import MongoClient from 'mongodb';
//...
MongoClient.Int32(1)
MongoClient.Long(2)
MongoClient.Decimal128(3)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var NumberInt = require("mongodb").Int32;
var dataToInsert = NumberInt(1)
```

Now this can be used wherever you would want to insert a value as Int.

Comment: Would help to use a modern syntax (ES Modules, `const`).

Comment: Yes, why not. Just import "mongodb" the right way and you are good to go.

Comment: A suggested way for recent times:
`const { Int32: NumberInt } = require('mongodb');`